# Replace . with _ in json file and write it to table using python

Tags: python, json, database

How to replace . with _ in my json file,  and push the result json file to DB table.

Tried the below code but not working:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import sys
import os
import psycopg2
import glob
import traceback
import csv

user= sys.argv[2]
password = sys.argv[3]
host = sys.argv[4]
port = sys.argv[5]
db = sys.argv[6]
documenttype = sys.argv[7]
schema_name =  sys.argv[8]

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://'+user+':'+password+'@'+host+':'+port+'/'+db)
print("Database is connected")

data = sys.argv[1]
output_path = sys.argv[9]
for fileName in os.listdir(data):
    file = open(data+fileName, "r",encoding='utf-8')
    contents = file.read()
    if '.' in contents:        
        with open(output_path+fileName,'w',encoding='utf-8') as output:
            rmSplc=contents.replace('.','_')
            output.write(rmSplc)
            print(". replaced with _ in file")


df = pd.read_json(rmSplc)

df['RecordsNew'] = df['Records'].astype('|S80')

df_1 = pd.json_normalize(df['Records'])
df_1.columns = map(str.lower, df_1.columns)
table_name =documenttype.lower()

             
df_1.to_sql(table_name,schema=schema_name,con=engine, if_exists = 'append',index=False)
```

But getting below error:

```
Database is connected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xdata/dev/ariba/python/JSON_PYTHON_RESPONSE.py", line 36, in <module>
    for fileName in os.listdir(data):
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '{"Records":[{"ExceptionType":{"ExceptionTypeId":"UnderTaxVariance-SAP"},"InvoiceLineNumber":2,"ExceptionStatus":"Unreconciled","InvoiceSubmissionMethod":"PaperInvoice","AccountingDate":{"Day":"2020-02-19T00:00:00Z"},"OrderID":null,"InvoiceId":"IRC2347-R337-154","InvoiceWithExceptionCount":1,"Requester":{"SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-CHILD1","UserId":"","PasswordAdapter":""},"Supplier":{"SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-CHILD1","SupplierId":"sid111","SupplierLocationId":"sid111_loc1"},"InvoiceNumber":"C2347-R337","InvoiceDate":{"Day":"2020-02-20T00:00:00Z"},"IRStatus":"Reconciling","POId":null,"ReconciledBy":{"SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-CHILD1","UserId":"","PasswordAdapter":""},"LoadUpdateTime":"2020-02-19T19:27:38Z","ProcurementUnit":{"SourceSystem":"","UniqueName":""},"LoadCreateTime":"2020-02-19T19:27:38Z","InvoiceSourceDocument":"NoOrderInformation","POLineNumber":null,"SourceSystem":{"SourceSystemId":"SSP-sap-CHILD1"}}],"PageToken":"TlhXQ0FXVDJHMUV3Qg"}'
InvoiceExceptionsFactis created
ProjectFactSystemView
ProjectFact
```

Json Example:

```
{"Records":[{"CommodityId":"3470","SourceSystem":"SSP-generic-CHILD4","CommodityName":"ANCHOR BOLTS - BILL OF MATERIALS","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"468657","SourceSystem":"SSP-generic-CHILD4","CommodityName":"COOLING INSERT","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"836519","SourceSystem":"SSP-generic-CHILD4","CommodityName":"DIAPHRAGM 2ND STAGE PGT25","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"807525","SourceSystem":"SSP-generic-CHILD4","CommodityName":"MOBILE NOZZLE MACHINING 2ST MS5002C(S2N)","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"DEFAULT","SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-BH100","CommodityName":"DEFAULT ERP Commodity Code","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"0074","SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-BH100","CommodityName":"Parts for equip,mach","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"B14","SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-BH100","CommodityName":"Glycols & Glycol Eth","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"CSU","SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-BH100","CommodityName":"SPRINGS","CommodityType":""}],"PageToken":"TlhXQ0FVcTlzNE8rQQ"}
```

If I remove the code snippet to replace . with _ its working fine.
Data is being read, table created and data pushed to table too.
But want to replace the . to _ and then write it to table.
Suggestions to solve this will be of great help.

Comment: But what is the problem exactly? And could you add json content example.

Comment: JSON content example:

`{"Records":[{"CommodityId":"3470","SourceSystem":"SSP-generic-CHILD4","CommodityName":"ANCHOR BOLTS - BILL OF MATERIALS","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"DEFAULT","SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-BH100","CommodityName":"DEFAULT ERP Commodity Code","CommodityType":""},
{"CommodityId":"CSU","SourceSystem":"SSP-sap-BH100","CommodityName":"SPRINGS","CommodityType":""}],"PageToken":"TlhXQ0FVcTlzNE8rQQ"}`

Comment: Error im getting:

`Database is connected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xdata/dev/ariba/python/JSON_PYTHON_RESPONSE.py", line 42, in <module>
    for fl in glob.iglob(df_1):
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/glob.py", line 40, in _iglob
    dirname, basename = os.path.split(pathname)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 107, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
InvoiceExceptionsFactis created
ERPCommodityDimSystemView
ERPCommodityDim`

Comment: you should update your question, not post it as a comment

Comment: Yes thanks for the suggestion, updated the question with both error, and sample json file too.
Scenario needed : The data should be read, if "." found then should be replaced with "_" and then pushed to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if replacing is the only issue in your code try this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
input_path='E:/CD034591Q_001log5.json'
output_path='E:/CD034591Q_001log5.json' 

file = open(input_path, "r",encoding='utf-8')
contents = file.read()
if '' in contents:        
    with open(output_path,'w',encoding='utf-8') as output:
        rmSplc=contents.replace('','')
        output.write(rmSplc)
```

Comment: I tried to incorporated your code, but somehow getting above error saying file name too long (have updated my question). The data should be read, if "." found then should be replaced with "_" and then pushed to table. Not sure where i went wrong, pls help

Comment: @Roho the code I mentioned above for set of JSON files placed in one folder, fileName in for loop (5th line) is files from folder taken one by one(eg :file1.json, file2.json...etc,.). if you want to run for only one file, just mention the path and start it from (6th line), just open the file, read and replace it.  os.listdir for read a several files placed in one folder, here the heading of the json is takes in fileName, if you still didn't get it, please mention it I will edit my code

Comment: Manju, I’m still not able to get it. Kindly can you edit your code. Would be of great help

Comment: @Roho, edited just give the input and output file as same as above mentioned